# Connect my Azure Web App to On-Premises SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a new web app in Azure that im trying to connect to my on-premises SQL server and following the instructions on [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started/).

I have opened up our firewall and configured an IP address to route it through port 1433.

I have setup, in Azure a Biz Talk hybrid connection (i have set the host name to the IP address and said port)  and the Connection manager has been installed locally.

I have set the following connection string in web.config

```
<add name="MyContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=<IPADDRESS>\<SQLINSTANCE>,1433;Initial Catalog=MyCatalogue;
     Network Library=DBMSSOCN;User ID=<USER>;Password=<PASS>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

I have [confirmed](http://www.t1shopper.com) that the said IP address is responding on port 1433

I am getting the following error
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such host is known]

Can anyone help me please with what I might have missed

Comment: Have you tried porting you app as Cloud Service(with Remote)/VM (with Web Deploy) ? These options provide a way to troubleshoot connectivity from the Azure End.

Comment: Im getting an error now. Possibly as i have increased the logging. And now getting Access is Denied

Comment: [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

Comment: It has been confirmed that the internal network is correctly configured, so now looking at the Azure side, Im not very happy with my connection string at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was that I wasn't using the Default SQL Server instance so corrected that.

I then had to address the database using the External IP address we setup not our private one, which according to the Azure documentation we didn't need, strange.

But i don't think the connection is using the Hybrid connection though and directly connecting to the DB

Answer (score 0):

Change your **connectionString** to "*Server*=IPADDRESS...."

Comment: This hasnt made a difference im afraid.